# How to refer to data in a previous viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an android project that is using fragments and a viewpager.
I am using a separate countdown timer for every page, that only runs when the view of the page is 'onscreen'. At first the time for every page is the same, but after a while page 1 might be 20 seconds left, page 2 60 seconds and so on.

My problem is that I don't know how to save the remaining time, the moment the user swipes to the next page. I am using a onpagestatelistener that has the following code, but this is saving the new value of questionId and the old value of the new time. How do I refer to the value of the questionId and the matching newtime-value of the page that was in view before the user swiped?

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
            saveTime();
        }
    }
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {}
    public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
        questionId =  mQuestions.get(pos).getNr()
        runTime();
    }
});

public void saveTime(){
    mQuestions.get(questionId).setTime(newTime);
}

public void runTime(){
    if (mTimer != null) {
        mTimer.cancel();
        mTimer = null;
    }
    mTimer = new CountDownTimer(90000, 1000) {//MillisInFuture, countDownInterval
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            newTime = (millisUntilFinished/1000);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: What does that ViewPager hold? Is it a View or Fragment?

Comment: It holds a Fragment and is set up in the activity. The fragment is holding the view. 
If I would add the timer in the fragment view, it would count down even if the view would be in the background, which is why I added this here.

Comment: You can right a callback method to pause and resume the time. Refer to setUserVisibleHint method in the fragment

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use `SharedPreferences`.

Besides, of course you can save data in adapter which you use for ViewPager, you can save this data in DB or create some singleInstance in your parent Activity or Fragment.